# Multi Port Network Application

Tags: python, sockets, networking, process

I want to create a python network application that can run on multiple ports (ex: TCP:1234, TCP:5678, etc).

So I have lets say n number of Sockets, each listening for a client connection. I programmed a simple network application that listens to a range of ports but when I run the application it gets stuck at the listening phase of the first socket process!

How can I make my single python program when run to listen to N number of ports and each waiting for a client to connect to it. All sockets are running and listening at the same time.

```
Socket/Process #1: Listening on TCP Port 5000
Socket/Process #2: Listening on TCP Port 5001
Socket/Process #3: Listening on TCP Port 5002
...
Socket/Process #N: Listening on TCP Port 6000
```

Appreciate any ideas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python

import socket

def getPortList():
    ports=[]
    nPort=int(raw_input("# how many ports you want? "))
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,nPort):
        ports.append(int(raw_input("Enter port number: ")))
        j+=1
    return ports

def myTCPSocket(port=5000):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(("", int(port)))
    print ("\nWaiting for connections!\n")
    s.listen(5)
    (clientsock, clientaddr) = s.accept()
    print(clientaddr)

    data = "start"

    while len(data):
                clientsock.send("\nWelcome to Echo Server\n")
                data = clientsock.recv(1024)
                print ("Data sent is: ", data)
                clientsock.send(data)
                if data == "exit\r\n":
                        clientsock.close()

plst = getPortList()

for item in plst:
    myTCPSocket(item)
```

Comment: How are you handling multiple connections on the same socket? An explicit `select` loop, `asyncore`, a higher-level reactor or proactor like Twisted, a thread for each connection, a process for each connection, …? Whatever you do for that will also work for multiple listener sockets. Your output implies that you've got a separate process for each listener, which should work. Can you show us the code that "gets stuck"?

Comment: Currently I don't have any multiple connections enabled to the same socket. Only one client can connect to the socket. Its fine for now. The problem is with running the python program and letting it fork or create a socket/process for each port so a client can connect to it.

Comment: You really would be better off designing for multiple client connections, at which point this problem becomes trivial. However, if you really want to solve this problem without that one, forking (or, better, using `multiprocessing`) for each socket should work just fine. Again, what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Sorry abarnet, I'm unable to add all the code here, I added it here: [link](http://pastebin.com/5M6dP5NG)

Comment: Well, you have a function called myTCPSocket that accepts one client and doesn't return until the client goes away. Then you call this function once per socket. So it's going to wait for a client on port 5000 to connect, do stuff, and go away; then wait for a client on port 5001 to connect, do stuff, and go away; and so on. All code is synchronous unless you do something to make it asynchronous (multithreading, multiprocessing, event loop, etc.). See my two examples to see two different ways of doing this.

Comment: I will have to read them, I'm totally new here and it seems that I must read a lot of stuff. Your reply for sure will help me start, and appreciate if you have any other resources for me to read. Also, do you recommend I use multithreading? multiprocessing? even-loop? event-driven? or what? My application is supposed to handle each port differently, but for the time being I just want it to run. Thank you abarnet.

Comment: Let me modify my answer to give more information.

Answer (score 2):

Listening on multiple sockets is really no different from listening on a single socket.

You already need to handle the listener socket and all client connection sockets somehow. You can do this by:

- Writing a loop around `select.select` (or `poll`, `kqueue`, `epoll`, etc.).
- Using the standard-library reactor `asyncore`.
- Using a third-party reactor or proactor like Twisted.
- Using OS-specific functionality (e.g., using a Cocoa runloop and server via PyObjC).
- Creating a thread for each new connection.
- Creating a subprocess for each new connection.

Almost all of these schemes will also work for dealing with multiple listeners. The simplest thing to do is to combine the two into one (e.g., a single `select` loop that handles all of their listeners and all of their client sockets, or a separate thread for each listener and client socket).

For performance or debugging reasons, you might want to instead use a two-tier hybrid approach (e.g., a thread for each listener, each with a `select` loop for all of its client sockets, or a process for each listener, each with a thread for each client socket). But if you don't have any good reason to do that, don't add the complexity.

http://pastebin.com/QebZMKz3 shows a simple single-`select` implementation. Here's the output:

```
$ ./multiserve.py 22222 22223 &
(('127.0.0.1', 22222), ' listening')
(('127.0.0.1', 22223), ' listening')
$ echo 'abc' | nc localhost 22222
(('127.0.0.1', 22222), ' <- ', ('127.0.0.1', 64633))
(('127.0.0.1', 64633), ' <- ', 'abc\n')
(('127.0.0.1', 64633), ' EOF')
```

If you think you'll never actually need to handle two simultaneous clients… well, you're probably wrong, but… You can use most of the above techniques, and it may be marginally simpler. For example, you can select on the listeners, and then do the accept and client-socket communication synchronously before returning to the loop. Or you can create a process or thread for each listener but handle the accept and client-socket communication synchronously within each. And so on.

http://pastebin.com/wLVLT49i shows a simple example that seems to be what you were trying to do. Since it uses a process for each socket (via `os.fork`), it does allow simultaneous connections on different ports; since it doesn't do anything asynchronously within each process, it doesn't allow simultaneous connections to the same port. (And of course it's POSIX-specific because it uses `fork`.)

If you're looking to learn how to write asynchronous network servers in the first place, I'd suggest you do two different implementations: `select` and threads. They conceptually fundamental, and relatively easy to code.

First, for `select`, you have to get your head around the idea of an event loop—the events are each new incoming connection, each incoming network packet on an existing connection, even each time a pipe you were writing to gets unclogged. The tricky bit here is that, as with any event loop, you need to handle each event and return without blocking, and without spending too much CPU time. For example, for an echo server, you can't just do a write on the other sockets, because some of them might be busy. So instead, you have to stick the output in a write buffer for each socket, and they'll get it in some future run through the event loop, when thye're ready.

Meanwhile, for threads, a separate thread for each connection seems like it makes everything trivial, but what happens when you need to echo a message from one thread to another? You either need some form of inter-thread communication, or shared data with inter-thread synchronization. So, you might have a `Queue` for writes on each socket, so any other socket's thread can just push a message onto the queue.

Neither of these will be as good as what a well-turned reactor or proactor can do, but it'd worth learning the basics—especially since you're going to face both the blocking issue (from `select`) and the communication issue (from threads) with any solution, and they'll be much more mysterious and harder to debug when you're working at a higher level.

Comment: abarnet, thank you very much for all that help. I have to read them and do some testing and get back to you. Do you have any other resources you recommend I read on top of your reply?

Comment: Google for "Python select example" and you should find some good blog posts.

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you. You really made my life much more easier. BTW: Do I have to mark the thread as solved? Or can I take a day reading and get back?

Comment: I think you can do some reading and make sure it really is solved before marking it that way, because I'm not sure you can undo that mark…

Comment: I had a problem with my account, solved it today. Now I have a problem: its when I do any port scan on these services the whole program shuts down! Why can't I port scan these services? Or open ports? And is there a good place to read about these Python Networking issues? Thanks for your help, wouldn't have reached this steps without your help.

Comment: This was meant to be a quick&dirty example to show the idea, so I left out real error handling. My guess is the problem was calling `getpeername` even on sockets known to be shutdown (after getting them in the `x` list, or after `recv` returned an EOF), which a real server wouldn't ever do. But the `recv` itself could fail with an intentionally nasty client. (By the way, testing with tools like nmap, or whatever you used, is a great idea if you plan to put your server on the internet.) Fortunately, Python makes error handling pretty easy. See http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QebZMKz3

Comment: Is the code in your last post the solution to such a test? Yes I'm testing the port with Nmap, but it directly crashes. I really wish if you could tell me in which area I'm doing wrong, and where to read. Thank you very much abarnert, and sorry for my late replies.

Comment: It looks like the pastebin I gave doesn't have the changes. Try http://pastebin.com/AD6iAJ1H. You really should look through the [Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sockets.html) and Google for Python `select` tutorials, because an SO answer can really only cover the basics, and at this point we're not dealing with anything specific to listening on multiple ports, it's just generic server stuff.

Comment: I want to do a simple service that I can test using lets say Nmap. The application has to run on different ports, thats why I needed that. The problem is now I'm getting the application to crash whenever I do a scan! I tested the new code you gave me, it also gives the same problem and crashes the app. I really appreciate all your kind help.

Comment: Saying "crashes the app" doesn't help at all. You have to say how it fails, with what message, and where. Also, what version of Python are you running on? If it's not 3.3, did you read the comments saying what needs to be changed?

Comment: Hi abarnert, I read your posts went through the comments you made, but honestly didn't understand all of it! I might need some further reading :( I'm totally new to network programming, and there seems to be lots of stuff I'm missing. To answer your questions: I'm using python 2.7, and the error messages are the ones I added to the pastbin link. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: @SysOps: I'm guessing you didn't read the comments at lines 47-50. Since I didn't know which Python version you were using, I didn't know which error to handle; if you want it to work with 2.7, you need to use `IOError` instead of `OSError`. And again at line 74, and anywhere else. You may want to look at the source to `asyncore` in the stdlib (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/asyncore.py), in particular the functions from `read` through `loop`, which does all the same stuff, and is more complete (but has added complexity from things like "use poll instead of select if possible").

Comment: Sorry abarnert, I forgot to mention that I did use the IOError, and now the application is able to not crash after a port scan. There is some bugs in it, especially when maybe I want to send back to the scanner a message, I get that the pipe is broken and stuff like that. So sorry mate, I really did read all of your comments, but I don't have your python skills, I'm still new here. I will stick with this way of coding using the select, its working now even though some bugs in it.