# Python Network Socket Crashes after Port Scan

Tags: python, networking, port, port-scanning

In reference to this question:
[Multi Port Network Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130116/multi-port-network-application)

I want to thank **abarnert** for all the help he gave me. Now the problem is that the program crashes and gives me:

error: [Error 104] Connection reset by peer

This happens when I do a port scan on the python services I'm running.

Comment: How can I make the service not crash when a port scanner scans the port?